# Warum wird "Art + Genitiv" ohne Artikel benutzt?

Tags: genitive

> Die bestimmte Art Bücher

Wo ist denn *der*? Sollte es nicht *die bestimme Art der Bücher* heißen?

Comment: Dieser Satz kein Verb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der bestimmte Artikel wird für **bestimmte** Dinge benutzt. Leider kommt in deinem Beispiel das Wort *bestimmte* vor, was die Antwort etwas verwirrend machen würde. Ich ersetze dieses Wort daher durch *besondere*:

> die besondere Art Bücher

Es geht um Bücher im allgemeinen, nicht um bestimmte, zuvor bereits erwähnte Bücher.

> die besondere Art der Bücher

Es wurden zuvor schon Bücher erwähnt und diese werden nun noch weiter unterteilt oder beschrieben.